# Java : ADF control value cannot be displyed on browser

Tags: java, oracle-adf

binding adf control value to a bean property and run the jsf or jspx file on browser , then value can not be displayed

Here is a vidoe to explain the problem  .. would you please have a key
for this . can not execute a lot of work because of this

https://www.facebook.com/mohamed.morsy.71697/videos/1449889981768665/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please do not post links to external resources.

Comment: What @TimothyTruckle said.  Especially for those of us at work who aren't allowed to visit websites such as facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wrap the output text inside a group component ( maybe a panel group layout) and set it's partial trigger property with the button Id. This way the panel will listen button actions and is how the text will be updated when you click it.

Comment: Thank u Juan Carlos Mendoza  very much .. it Worked